# Graceful decommissioning on Spot/Standard pre-emptible nodes in DataProc cluster in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-dataproc, graceful-shutdown

We are trying to setup a DataProc cluster in GCP.

While we do, we try to have secondary nodes which are either Spot VMs or Standard pre-emptible VMs (to note: spot VMs are also pre-emptible).

When we do graceful decommissioning on the **Spot / Standard pre-emptible VMs**, will graceful decommissioning be in effect?
(the node will not be reclaimed until the tasks running in the node are complete / the graceful decommissioning reaches its threshold time limit)

[OR]

The VMs will be immediately reclaimed back by GCP? (forceful decommissioning)

Could someone please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you follow this [Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/configuring-clusters/scaling-clusters#console_1) for Graceful decommissioning and please let us know if it is useful for you or not ? and you can check these 2 link also [Link1](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/spot) and [Link2](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/preemptible).

Comment: Hi Arpita, thanks for your time looking into the query. 

Actually we are explicitly looking for how the Spot/Standard pre-emptible VMs behave when graceful-decommissioning is initiated against them.
We perceive the behaviour could be one of them:
1. They will be forcefully taken back by GCP when GCP needs them (graceful-decommissioning will not be in effect in this case)
2. Graceful-decommissioning will be in effect (GCP will wait until the tasks in the VMs are complete/graceful-decommissioning time threshold is reached).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The latter "The VMs will be immediately reclaimed back by GCP (forceful decommissioning)" is correct. Dataproc is built on top of GCE. Graceful decommissioning is a (YARN cluster level) Dataproc feature while spot/pre-emptible VMs are GCE features. Dataproc has no control over the underlying GCE behavior. You need to avoid spot/pre-emptible VMs if you need graceful decommissioning.